# Difficult boundary conditions for the PDE $U_{xx}=U_t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given $U_{xx}=U_t$, $U_x(1,t)=U(1,t)$, and $U_x(0,t)=0$. I use separation of variables and set $U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then

$$X''T=XT'$$
$$\frac{X''}X=\frac{T'}T=-\lambda$$

for some $\lambda$. And

$$X''+\lambda X=T'+\lambda T=0$$

then $T=e^{-\lambda t}$ and $\lambda>0$, as for $\lambda\leq0$ the boundary conditions can't be satisfied except for the trivial solution. I'm certain that $X=\cos(\sqrt\lambda x)$, although at this point I am lost as to how I should proceed, since attempting to factor in the boundary values at this point gives

$$-\sqrt\lambda\sin(\sqrt\lambda)=\cos(\sqrt\lambda)$$

which, as far as I can tell, can only be numerically approximated for the value of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your proof.  For a Robin boundary condition such as   yours:    $U_x(1,t) = U(1,t)$ the solution is indeed of the form:
$$\tan{\sqrt{\lambda}} = -\sqrt{\lambda}$$
This doesn't have any closed form solutions (as far as I know) so you must indeed find the eigenvalues numerically.  If I'm not mistaken, the first few are:

$$\lambda_1 = 2.029 \quad \lambda_2 = 4.913 \quad \lambda_3 = 7.979$$